# show video in SweetAlert

Tags: javascript, php, html, sweetalert, vue-sweetalert2

Good afternoon, I'm using SweetAlert to show notifications, looking in the official SweetAlert documents they show some examples, for example to show images, but what I'm trying to do is show a youtube video.

[SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)

```
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Sweet!',
  text: 'Modal with a custom image.',
  imageUrl: 'https://unsplash.it/400/200',
  imageWidth: 400,
  imageHeight: 200,
  imageAlt: 'Custom image',
})
```

Any recommendation to show Youtube video on SweetAlert.

Some examples I have done is embed the video with iframe:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/d_elXY2Lcfk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But I want that just by placing the path I can see the video.

Answer (score 3):

In the documentation, you can use custom html as the alert body

```
Swal.fire({
  title: '<strong>HTML <u>example</u></strong>',
  icon: 'info',
  html:
    '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/d_elXY2Lcfk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
  showCloseButton: true,
  showCancelButton: true,
  focusConfirm: false,
  confirmButtonText:
    '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Great!',
  confirmButtonAriaLabel: 'Thumbs up, great!',
  cancelButtonText:
    '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>',
  cancelButtonAriaLabel: 'Thumbs down'
})
```